# Neo4j: How to limit subqueries

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I just imported the English Wikipedia into Neo4j and am playing around. I started by looking up the pages that link into the Page "Berlin"

```
MATCH p=(p1:Page {title:"Berlin"})<-[*1..1]-(otherPage)
WITH nodes(p) as neighbors
LIMIT 500
RETURN DISTINCT neighbors
```

That works quite well. What I would like to achieve next is to show the 2nd degree of relationships. In order to be able to display them correctly, I would like to limit the number of first degree relationship nodes to 20 and then query the next level of relationship.

How does one achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Wikipedia model, but I'm assuming that there are many different relationship types and that is why that -[*1..1]-, I think that is analogous to -[]- or even --. I doubt it has any serious impact though.

You can collect up the first level matches and limit them to 20 using a WITH with a LIMIT. You can then perform a second match using those (<20) other pages as the start point.

```
MATCH (p1:Page {title:"Berlin"})<-[*1..1]-(otherPage:Page)
WITH p1, otherPage
LIMIT 20
MATCH (otherPage)<-[*1..1]-(secondDegree:Page)
WHERE secondDegree <> p1
WITH otherPage, secondDegree
LIMIT 500
RETURN otherPage, COLLECT(secondDegree)
```

There are many ways to return the data, this just returns the first degree match with an array of the subsequent matches.

If the only type of relationship is :Link and you want to keep the start node then you can change the query to this:

```
MATCH (p1:Page {title:"Berlin"})<-[:Link]-(otherPage:Page)
WITH p1, otherPage
LIMIT 20
MATCH (otherPage)<-[:Link]-(secondDegree:Page)
WHERE secondDegree <> p1
WITH p1, otherPage, secondDegree
LIMIT 500
RETURN p1, otherPage, COLLECT(secondDegree)
```

Comment: Thanks. The structure is very simple (in my model). It is just one ":Link" type of relationship. Your solution seems to only return the direct neighbors and second degree neighbors. But leaves out the first start node, which would be Berlin. Is there a way to change that?